# how to make URL link query string

Tags: urls, archives, links, meta-query, query-string

I have pages with a custom meta field called "ctr_state", and it contains a state name, like "Arizona".

I am trying to construct a hyperlink that will return an archive-like list of pages that match the meta_value I am looking for.

For instance,

```
<a href="http://mydomain.com/?type=page&amp;meta_key=ctr_state&amp;meta_value=Arizona">Show All Arizona Pages</a>
```

This isn't working, but is just to show how I want it to work as a link. I don't want a list on the page, I just want it to link to an archive type page, showing just the page's that match the state I'm looking for.

Is this possible?

Comment: To do this with a custom field you could write a [Page Template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates). If you are not already too invested in the custom field switching to a [Custom Taxonmy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) would allow you to go to a url that matches any state name with WordPress doing much of the work for you. No template needed (unless you want to customize it).

Comment: If I used a template, would I need to create an empty page to assign the template to, in order to link to it, or is there a way to link directly to a template and not having it assigned to any particular page?

Comment: The former is the normal case. Before that page template PHP file is executed, WordPress loads, any plugins, the theme and perhaps a few other things happen; Then that code is executed. If you went directly to the file you would have to manually start all that stuff first and then add your template code. I would suggest trying it the way WordPress programmers expect you to do so (using a page template or a custom taxonomy) and get that working and try something more exotic later.

Comment: Thanks Charles. This helped me, and have it working now. For many reasons I couldn't use taxonomy nor have placeholder pages in this project. I was able to add a function for a template redirect:

Comment: This is how I got it working:
ADDED this to functions.php:
`function include_template_function( $template_path ) {
 global $wp;
    if ($wp->request == 'state') {
  $template_path = locate_template( array ( 'state.php' ) );
 }
 return $template_path;
}`
ADDED THIS to the base template (page.php):
`<?php 
 $baseURL = esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );
 $ak_link = $baseURL . 'state?st=AK';
?>
<a href="<?php echo $ak_link; ?>">Show Alaska Pages</a>`

CREATED state.php template that handles state queries:
`<?php 
 $st = $_GET['st'];
 get_header(); ?>
?>`
and can test for $st and do stuff accordingly.

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting. First time using stackexchange.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and accept it. It will help others with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I got it working:

ADDED this to functions.php:

```
function include_template_function( $template_path ) {
    global $wp;
    if ($wp->request == 'state') {
        $template_path = locate_template( array ( 'state.php' ) );
    }
    return $template_path;
}

$state_name = $_GET['st']; //this is added to use as a global variable
```

ADDED THIS to header.php because WP thinks it's serving a 404 page

```
    if ($wp->request == 'state') { 
        echo 'Member Centers in ' . $state_name . ' | ';
    } else {
        wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );
    } 
?>
</title>
```

ADDED THIS to the base template (page.php):

```
<?php 
    $baseURL = esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );
    $ak_link = $baseURL . 'state?st=Alaska'; // for each state
?>
<a href="<?php echo $ak_link; ?>">Show Alaska Pages</a>
```

CREATED state.php template that handles state queries:

```
<?php global $state_name; ?> ?>

<?php 
    $mypages = get_pages('child_of='.$parent_page_id.'&sort_order=ASC&parent='.$parent_page_id.'&meta_key=ctr_state&meta_value='.$state_name);
    foreach($mypages as $page)
    {
?>
... Do Stuff! ...
<?php } ?>
```